# Number Format Exception for String 13363190467160024386 while converting to Long

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert a `numeric String` to `Long`, but it is giving me `NumberFormatException`.

I am getting `NumberFormatException` for this String `13363190467160024386`

Long.parseLong(String s)

Below is the exception I am getting-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "13363190467160024386"
```

Any suggestions why is it happening?

Comment: it's too long to be long

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely - that number is greater than than [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) (9223372036854775807).

Use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("13363190467160024386");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is outside the range of `Long`.

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println("13363190467160024386");
```

Prints: -

```
9223372036854775807
13363190467160024386
```

You should use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to store numbers greater than that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that number is too big for a signed `long`

<strike>maybe try an unsigned `long`</strike> never-mind, apparently java doesn't have one.  1 more reason why c# > java

2^64 =  1.8446744e+19

Answer (score 1):

Maximum Long is:

```
9223372036854775807
```

Your number is larger than this:

```
13363190467160024386
```

Answer (score 1):

Your number exceeds the limit of `long`, which is `2^63`, or roughly `9E18`. Your number is roughly `1.3E14`, triggering an error.